# Include windows.h

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, include

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between #include <filename> and #include “filename”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593/what-is-the-difference-between-include-filename-and-include-filename)

Is there a difference between:

```
#include "windows.h"
```

and

```
#include <windows.h>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Yes.

```
#include "something"
```

Tries to include file in current directory first, and

```
#include <something>
```

Always include file from system directories.

Comment: Congratulations for speed. Instant answer just before instant close.

Comment: ..And the "current directory" is the parent directory of the file containing that `#include`.